# Visual Workflow - Format the display of each record for an SObject Collection Variable?

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm using a Fast Lookup to retrieve a list of records in visual workflow.  I'd like to format the output on the screen (e.g. show one record per line).  Is this possible?  When I use the "Display Text" element all I can access is the collection's name and which spews all the information out in one big line.  Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to do this with looping through the records and displaying them individually.  At least that's Brian Kwong's opinion (http://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the page below.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000AwtcIAC

Summary:

- First, make a new variable (we'll call it varDisplayText) to hold all of your text.
- Then, in your loop, pass the Collection to a standard sObject Variable.
- From there, use an Assignment element to Add (not equals!) the first value of the first column to varDisplayText.
  Then (and I think you can do this in the same Assignment element, I am pretty sure it will do it in order), use varDisplayText again but instead of using Equals, use Add, and add the text string ", ".
- Add another line in the same element (or a new Assignment element if necessary), use varDisplayText again, with Add, then the first value in your second column.
- Add another line in the same element (or a new Assignment element if necessary), use varDisplayText again, with Add, then the comma text string again, but with a line break character afterwards.
- Point back to your loop so you can get the next set of values in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, this isn't possible anymore. You'll need to build a lightning component that then takes the collection variable and pass it into an aura iteration element (lighting). From there you can select what fields to display per item as well as format it to be more user friendly (html, css).

Comment: Could you please include some references to the documentation or release notes to support and clarify this answer?